# unable to find client.indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest) in elasticsearch 6.2.1

Tags: java, elasticsearch, maven-dependency, node-rest-client

I was trying to insert mapping in the RestHighLevelClient of elasticsearch 6.2.1

From the following link I had found the following code for the insertion of mapping

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html

```
    RestHighLevelClient client =  new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(ipaddress, port, "http")));
    client.indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest);
```

But I was unable to find putMapping(putMappingRequest) in the client.indices()

this is the maven dependency that I had added in the project

```
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1</version>
```

Can anyone help me to find out correct jar file that suits my requirement or any other way to insert mapping using RestHighLevelClient

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link points to the documentation of an unreleased version. For 6.2.1, you need to use the [`CreateIndexRequest`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-create-index.html), like this:

```
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("twitter"); 
request.mapping("tweet", 
    "  {\n" +
    "    \"tweet\": {\n" +
    "      \"properties\": {\n" +
    "        \"message\": {\n" +
    "          \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
    "        }\n" +
    "      }\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "  }", 
    XContentType.JSON);
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(request);
```

Comment: thanks @Val, but I was also not able find client.indices().exists(request) can you suggest any alternative

Comment: The documentation you should be looking at is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-create-index.html . The exists method is not yet supported in that version.

Comment: can you suggest elasticsearch version and document that supports rest high level client

Comment: Unfortunately, the feature you're requesting is not yet released. It might come into ES 6.3, though. In the meantime, you can achieve what you want with the [low-level REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low.html) instead